# Entity framework wrong date saving

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, date, datetime

I create new DateTime variable, fill it with some date and specify it as UTC (DateTime.SptcifyKind). Then i put this date to entity and call SaveChanges(). Later in SQLite i see local date (not UTC), what is totally wrong. 
For example, i'm trying to save `2014-02-11 8:47:05` (UTC), but then in db the record has value `2014-02-11 10:47:05` (local time, +2 UTC). 
 
Can somebody help me to figure it out? Is there some kind of automatic convertion to local time or what i'm doing wrong?

BTW, this problem occurs only on another computers, on my PC date is saving in proper way.

Comment: How are you looking at what the database has stored? Perhaps it's whatever you're using to look at it which is converting it back to a local value?

Comment: It was my first thought. I'm using SQLite Expert trial, but Entity framework is returning wrong date too.

Comment: Hmm. Is there anywhere you can configure the EF behaviour? I'm afraid I don't know much about EF, but date/time handling is always a pain...

Comment: Is the [Kind property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx) of the datetime variable set to [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of "Unspecified" or "Local"?

Comment: Yeah, i'm using something like `DateTime newValue = System.DateTime.SpecifyKind(eventTime, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);` and passing this newValue further.

Comment: It's probably outdated, but does any of [this](http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/06/16/Forcing-Entity-Framework-to-mark-DateTime-fields-at-UTC.aspx) or [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/467142) help?

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe there is some kind of configure file, but i cannot find it and google didnt help me in it.

Comment: @RobIII Thanks for the link, but I already tried it.